# python point inside polygon (point cloud data)

Tags: python, csv, point, point-clouds

## number of points 100,000,000 (4GB)

I am reading a CSV file and saving the data separate CSV file.

I'm using import csv.reader, which is working fine. But this code I noticed that it takes too much time.

How can I improve the performance of my task?

Please provide me with alternative options.

Performance is the main concern here.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import csv
import os

req1 = input("path of the CSV file: ")

file_name = os.path.splitext(req1)
file_name = os.path.split(file_name[0])
path = file_name[0]
file_name = file_name[1]

with open(req1, "r") as f:  
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip header

    os.makedirs(path + "/" + file_name + "_output", exist_ok=True)
    outpath = path + "/" + file_name + "_output" + "/"

    coords = [[19.803499,15.2265],[-35.293499,33.7495],
            [-49.6675,33.726501],[-48.022499,20.4715],
            [-36.336498,-4.925],[-32.6105,-45.494499],
            [-10.5275,-38.3815],[-11.93835,-20.8235],
            [26.939501,-18.095501],[19.803499,15.2265]]

    poly = Polygon(coords)
    for row in reader:
        geom = Point(float(row[0]),float(row[1])) # Considering the order of elements that you gave
    
        x = float(row[0])
        y = float(row[1])
        z = float(row[2])
        r = int(row[3])
        g = int(row[4])
        b = int(row[5])
        i = int(row[6])
    
        result = geom.within(poly)
    
        if str(result) == 'True':
          with open(outpath + file_name + "_TRUE.csv", "a", newline = "") as file:
            writeData = ([str(x),',',str(y),',',str(z),',',str(r),',',str(g),',',str(b),',',str(i),('\n')])
            file.writelines(writeData)
            print('True', str(x),str(y),str(z))
        else:
          with open(outpath + file_name + "_FALSE.csv", "a", newline = "") as file:
            writeData = ([str(x),',',str(y),',',str(z),',',str(r),',',str(g),',',str(b),',',str(i),('\n')])
            file.writelines(writeData)
            #print('False', str(x),str(y),str(z))
```

Comment: It's unclear what your "code" is. Possible options for making your code faster would be to parse out the data and run in parallel, or maybe porting to Cython or numba.

Comment: @AndrewH, Please check the code.

Comment: Yeah, you could easily parallelize the "for row in reader" loop. I'd suggest just plain Python multiprocessing. Cython would probably be a bit faster, if you really wanted to eek out the most. Also, without profiling this is just a guess, but the long run time is likely due to line "result = geom.within(poly)." There could be a faster algorithm there, for finding if the point is in the polygon, lots of stuff on convex hulls to choose from.

Comment: @AndrewH I have a Question. Please check the new code.

Answer (score 0):

I used [pd.read_csv] instead of [import csv.reader].

So the performance has been improved a bit.

However, I tried to do Python multiprocessing, 
but I don't understand it well.

Process result time (1234 sec -> 31 sec)

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import *

data = pd.read_csv("/sample.csv")
poly = Polygon([(-0.7655,-22.758499), (17.0525,-21.657499),   (16.5735,-26.269501), (0.4755,-28.6635)])
cord = data.values.tolist()

for i in cord:
    print(poly.intersects(Point(i[0], i[1])), i)
```

for example code of Python Multiprocessing Pools
[enter link description here](https://dev.to/terrillo/a-quick-introduction-to-python-multiprocessing-pools-speeding-up-your-workflow-17op)

```
import time 
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x):
  time.sleep(2) # Wait 2 seconds
  print(x*x)
p = Pool(8)
p.map(f, [1, 2, 3, 4])
p.close()
p.join()
```

How should I apply this?

Comment: Multiprocessing would go something like this, vals = p.map(lambda x: poly.intersects(Point(x[0], x[1])), cord)